# Python add pytest --black to test suite

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I use pytest for testing my Python project. What I want to do is to add to my test suite a function to check whether my code is formatted in "Black" or not. When I press the command `"pytest --black"` my whole project is tested as I want to. How can I add this function in my tests suite and check the same thing when I run the `"python setup.py pytest"` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pytest.ini`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html)  [has an `addopts` key](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-addopts) which does literally what it says on the tin: it adds options to the `pytest` command line you used.

So at the root of your program, you should be able to just create a `pytest.ini` file containing:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --black
```

and it should automatically enable black-as-test on your pytest runs.